# How to adjust index in tmy_data output from iotools.read_tmy3 function. How I fixed my issue should others have the same problem

Tags: python, pandas, pvlib

Rather than a question, this is more of my workaround for a problem I was having when reading tmy3 files. I hope that it can be of use to some of you. I am still a novice when it comes to coding and python, so there may be simpler ways.

## **PROBLEM**

Upon using the iotools.read_tmy3() function, I followed examples and code outlined by others. This included:
1. Reading the tmy3 datafile; 
2. Coercing the year to 2015 (or any other year you like); and,
3. Shifting my index by 30 minutes to match the solar radiation simulation.

The code I used was:

```
tmy_data, metadata = pvlib.iotools.read_tmy3(datapath, coerce_year=2015)
tmy_data = tmy_data.shift(freq='-30Min') ['2015']
tmy_data.index.name = 'Time
```

By using this code, you lose the final row of your DataFrame. This is resolved by removing the ['2015'] in line two resolves this, but now the final date is set in 2014. For the purpose of my work, I needed the final index to remain consistent.

## **WHAT I TRIED**

1. I attempted to shift index of the final row, unsuccessfully, using the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html) method.
2. I attempted to reindex by setting the index of the final row equal to the DatetimeIndex I wanted.
3. I attempted to remove the timezone data from the index, modify the index, then reapply the timezone data.
   All of these were overly complicated, and did not help resolve my issue.

## **WHAT WORKED FOR ME**

The code for what I did is shown below. These were my steps:
1. Identify the index from my final row, and copy its data;
2. Drop the final row of my tmy_data DataFrame;
3. Create a new dataframe with the shifted date and copied data; and,
4. Append the row to my tmy_data DataFrame

It is a bit tedious, but it an easy fix when reading multiple tmy3 files with multiple timezones.

```
#Remove the specific year from line 2 in the code above
tmy_data = tmy_data.shift(freq='-30Min')

#Identify the last row, and copy the data
last_date = tmy_data.iloc[[-1]].index

copied_data = tmy_data.iloc[[-1]]
copied_data = copied_data.to_dict(orient='list')

#Drop the row with the incorrect index
tmy_data.drop([last_date][0], inplace = True)

#Shift the date of the last date
last_date = last_date.shift(n = 1, freq = 'A')

#Create a new DataFrame with the shifted date and copied data
last_row = pd.DataFrame(data = copied_data, 
                        index=[last_date][0])

tmy_data = tmy_data.append(last_row)
```

After doing this my final indeces are:

```
2015-01-01 00:30:00-05:00
....
2015-12-31 22:30:00-05:00
2015-12-31 23:30:00-05:00
```

This way, the DataFrame contains 8760 rows, as opposed to 8759 through the previous method.

I hope this helps others!